# Images loading blurred or not loading - Gatsby and GitHub Pages

Tags: reactjs, npm, github-pages, gatsby

I am super new to gatsby and it's been a while since i touched any kind of web development project.

I am trying to create a photography portfolio using this gatsby template
https://github.com/LekoArts/gatsby-starter-portfolio-emilia and my github account (github pages).

The problem is in the main page the image im using as cover picture doesn't load and in the album I'm either getting a blurred version or a weird grayscale version. In development they work just fine.

I'm running on MacOS High Sierra and have tried Firefox, Chrome and Safari. (not sure if relevant)

Here are some dev v. deploy pictures.

[image: Dev menu with cover picture]

[image: Deployed menu with (no) cover picture]

[image: Dev album with pictures]

[image: Deployed album with blurred pictures]

I'll post some of the code; but if it's not enough just ask me about something and I'll update the question. I'm really not sure where to begin debugging.

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "photos",
  "description": "photo portfolio",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "author": "Alex Ingberg (hi@alexingberg.com)",
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "dev": "gatsby develop -o",
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "deploy": "gatsby build && gh-pages -d public --branch master",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx --fix --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "format": "prettier \"**/*.{md,mdx} \" --write",
    "lint:ci": "yarn lint --format junit -o results/eslint/result.xml",
    "cy:open": "cypress open",
    "cy:run": "cypress run",
    "cy:run:ci": "cypress run --browser chrome --reporter junit --reporter-options 'mochaFile=results/cypress/result.xml'",
    "test:e2e:dev": "cross-env CYPRESS_SUPPORT=y start-server-and-test dev http://localhost:8000 cy:open",
    "test:e2e:run": "cross-env CYPRESS_SUPPORT=y start-server-and-test develop http://localhost:8000 cy:run",
    "test:e2e:ci": "cross-env CYPRESS_SUPPORT=y start-server-and-test develop http://localhost:8000 cy:run:ci"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.6.3",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.17",
    "@mdx-js/mdx": "^1.0.10",
    "@mdx-js/react": "^1.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "gatsby": "^2.9.11",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.1.4",
    "gatsby-mdx": "^0.6.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-analytics": "^2.0.18",
    "gatsby-plugin-lodash": "^3.0.5",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.0.29",
    "gatsby-plugin-netlify": "^2.0.14",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^2.0.25",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.0.12",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.0.35",
    "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^2.0.12",
    "gatsby-plugin-styled-components": "^3.0.7",
    "gatsby-remark-external-links": "^0.0.4",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.0.29",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.1.18",
    "gh-pages": "^2.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "polished": "^3.2.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
    "react-spring": "^8.0.19",
    "styled-components": "^4.2.0",
    "styled-theming": "^2.2.0",
    "typeface-fira-sans": "^0.0.54",
    "typeface-montserrat": "^0.0.54"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "cypress": "^3.2.0",
    "cypress-testing-library": "^2.4.0",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.17.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.6.3",
    "gatsby-cypress": "^0.1.8",
    "prettier": "^1.17.0",
    "start-server-and-test": "^1.7.13"
  },
  "homepage": "https://www.alexingberg.com/photos",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/alexing/photos/issues"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "gatsby",
    "gatsby-starter",
    "gatsby-starter-portfolio",
    "alexing"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "n/a",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/alexing/photos.git"
  }
}
```

Also, in the develop branch of my repo you can find the complete source code.
https://github.com/alexing/photos/tree/develop

Thanks a million.

Comment: Your repo link is not working. If you can update it I might be able to help you. The images are blurred because the template is probably using an image optimization plugin (such as gatsby image). When the images are just blurred and are not loading, most of the times it means that are not linked correctly. Look in the network tab and see from where are they loading.

Comment: @OvidiuG im sorry, forgot the repo was private. Already made public. Please check now. Great advice though with the network tab, I’ll check as soon as I get home.

Comment: @OvidiuG I tried with the network tab... apparently they are not loading from anyplace apparently (or i cant find it). You can check yourself also if you want alexingberg.com/photos/berlin.
Thanks again

Comment: Hi! Sorry Alex, I've been pretty busy. I'll take a look over your code today and get back with an answer.

Comment: I'm still having the same issue 

Comment: Was there any solution? I'm having a similar problem.